# dagger.android not generating components under /test folder

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I need the processor to generate code for classes under the `test` folder.

I cannot find any related question here on SO that is valid for my case since everyone recommends to add `testAnnotationProcessor` but it doesn't work for me...

I'm using **Gradle 3.3.0**

**Dagger version 2.16**
Here is all the dependencies I have added

```
...
// Use 2.16 because further versions cause crashes
def dagger = "2.16"
// Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
// Dagger-Android
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"
// Dagger Kotlin
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"

// Test Dagger
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
// Test Dagger-Android
testImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger"
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"
// Test Dagger Kotlin
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"
...
```

Update: it doesn't work for androidTest, too. (Despite I have updated dependencies to use `testAndroidImplementation`, etc.)